# MySQL not refresh?

Tags: mysql, web, refresh

```
    <?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT Ban FROM players WHERE Name = "'.$user.'" LIMIT 1') or die(mysql_error().":".mysql_errno());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
echo 'User is banned';
}else {
echo 'User is not banned';

}
?>
```

And when user is unbanned still display on website "User is banned".
So it is not refreshing, but in mysql all ok.
someone help ?

Comment: I hope `$user` doesn't come from any sort of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **mysql_num_rows** returns the number of **fetched** rows.
You can solve your problem with:

```
SELECT id FROM players WHERE Name = "'.$user.'" AND Ban = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I dont remove tables. I change int only.

Comment: **mysql_num_rows** returns the fetched rows. In your case one (1) because the user exists in your table. You need use a boolean field to enable-disable a user. For example: **Ban** field must be a boolean value and your query must be change in: **SELECT id FROM players WHERE Name = "'.$user.'" AND Ban = 1 LIMIT 1** to check if a user is banned or not. :)